# Is there any way to bulk download all the signed document from DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

I have a requirement to download all the signed documents from DocuSign. Is there any way to bulk download all the signed documents from docusign?

Thanks

Comment: One of the first hits on google: https://support.docusign.com/en/answers/00083683

Comment: That question was added by me in docusign community. Since i didnt get any solution in docusign community. I am expecting a solution here in #docusignapi.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot download bulk documents from all envelopes in one single api call. You have to download documents for each envelope in one api call either using archive or combined in /documents end point.

Comment: First use the API to get a list of the envelopes you want. Then loop through the list, downloading the docs for each envelope. You may also want the certificates of completion for each envelope

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DocuSign Retrive for the same.

https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/Retrieve-Overview?language=en_US

Comment: A recent article on Retrieve. You'll need to work with Professional Services to acquire it, apparently, but it does permit account-wide download if you are an admin.

https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=oyh1657217277873&topicId=ktg1667856889750.html&_LANG=enus